# How to export godot project to apk

Tags: export, apk, godot, godot4

When I tried to make apk It gave me this error:
"All located 'apksigner' tools in C:/Users/dodik/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/build-tools failed to execute"

Keystore I created and all needed(I think) I downloaded^
[all my sdk tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrrKd.png)
[editor settings -> export -> android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQKwe.png)

Comment: Try this solution: https://ask.godotengine.org/148772/getting-trying-export-android-located-apksigner-failed-execute

Comment: Thats doesn`t work. I tried